# Google permission policy changes effect on a CRM app for READ_CALL_LOG permission

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, user-permissions, calllog

I am working on a CRM app which requires READ_CALL_LOG permission.

**Use Case**:
The user will make calls to customers and after the call, the user will enter the start time and end time of the call. I want to automate it using **Call Logs** by getting the start time, end time and duration which requires READ_CALL_LOG permission.

As we now know that Google has updated the permission policy, I want to know whether the above use case will be accepted or not.

Can I assume that my use case will come under the below exception?
[image]

Here is the [doc](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303?hl=en) for Permitted and Exempted use cases for SMS and READ_CALL_LOG.

Comment: You should assume nothing, best check with google to make sure

Comment: @TimCastelijns, can you tell how to check with google directly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about the policies of an app distribution channel and [such questions are considered to be off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic)

Comment: @CommonsWare, I think you got my question wrong. I am not asking a way to use READ_CALL_LOG permission and successfully upload it to Play Store. I just want to know whether my use case is ***Permitted*** or can be used in ***Exceptional cases*** from Google Permission Policies since I am not able to understand or figure out whether the exception in the picture is for my use case, so that I can decide whether to implement this feature or not.

Comment: The Google Permission Policies are policies for an app distribution channel. [Questions about the policies of an app distribution channel are considered to be off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Comment: @CommonsWare, does this [doc](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303?hl=en) come under policies for an app distribution channel?

Comment: @Joshua: Yes. It is poorly written, in that it should lead off with "the Play Store" rather than "Google Play".

Comment: @CommonsWare, ok then, is there any other place where I can clarify my question?

Comment: Probably not. I do not know of anywhere that an ordinary developer could ask for a ruling in advance over whether a particular app would be allowed to use certain permissions or not.

Comment: @CommonsWare, if I know in advance, I will be able to decide whether to invest my time in this feature or do some other work. That's why.

Comment: What you want is perfectly reasonable. It is not something that Google is set up to offer to everyone. In the end, only one person's decision matters: whoever at Google would review your eventual app. Everyone else can at best offer opinions, which is why this sort of thing is off-topic here. You are welcome to try out [other Android developer discussion areas](https://commonsware.com/andglobe) and get opinions, so long as you realize that they are just that: opinions. Or, talk to your corporate legal counsel, and see if they have suggestions for how to proceed.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes, have to decide how to proceed further. Thanks for your suggestion.